# Deserialization of JSON webservice in Android

Tags: android, web-services, json.net, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize this JSON array into my android project.

```
[{"Name":"Ban","Price":1},{"Name":"Banana","Price":1},{"Name":"chicken","Price":14},{"Name":"pizza","Price":16},{"Name":"slice","Price":1}]
```

I have made this webservice in Asp.net. 
The code I am using to deserialize it is below

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    String url="http://192.168.15.2/MyAndroid/InputCaller.aspx"; //do not use localhost
    String response=callWebService(url);

    List<Items> mObjectList =  new ArrayList<Items>() ;
    ItemsList list = null;
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    list = gson.fromJson(response, ItemsList.class);
    // list = getItemsList(response);
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Cart.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);    
}

public final ItemsList getItemsList (String jsonString)
{
    ItemsList il = null;
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    il = gson.fromJson(jsonString, ItemsList.class);
    return il;
}

public class ItemsList
{
    private List<ItemsContainer> items = new ArrayList<ItemsContainer>();

    public List<ItemsContainer> getItemsContainerList()
    {
        return items;
    }
}

class ItemsContainer
{
    Items items;
    public Items getItem()
    {
        return items;
    }
}

public class Items
{
    String Name;
    int Price;
}
```

It is not working and when I try to debug it I get this message on  list = gson.fromJson(response, ItemsList.class); 
Gson.class Source not found. 
This is my first deserialisation program and I would really appreciate if anybody help me with it. Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make things complicated by using further parent classes (as container) for *Items* class. Simply de-serialize all the items into a *List* object using Gson as below:

```
List<Items> listItems = (List<Items>) gson.fromJson(response,
                                       new TypeToken<List<Items>>(){}.getType());
```

now you've got all the Items in a List object: **listItems**

Comment: Waqas It worked I will mark it as answer after the period is over. Thank you, I want to transfer this data to a new activity and want to display it in a list.. Can you give me a rough sketch of how is it going to be done.

Comment: Thats pretty simple. Pass your json string to another activity using `Intent.putExtra("json", "all the json string");` and in receiving activity, retrieve the json string as `String strJson = getIntent().getExtras().getString("json");` and later use that *strJson* to reconstruct items' list object using the technique in my answer